# How to see a history of a deleted file/directory in Perforce?

Tags: perforce

I know the location and name of a directory that was later deleted.

I need to see its history, or at least the changelist in which it was deleted, preferably on a command line with `p4`.

`p4 filelog //depot/<path>/deleted_dir` prints `no such file(s).`

[The documentation of p4 filelog mentions](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v17.1/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_filelog.html) that `deleted` is one of the possible history actions, but I don't see how to get there. Neither [does global options documentation](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v17.1/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/global.options.options.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a *directory* then you'll need to put the "..."

```
p4 filelog //depot/<path>/deleted_dir/...
```

will work

Answer (score 1):

You probably want:

```
p4 changes -m1 //depot/<path>/deleted_dir/...
```

The last change to affect that path will be the one that deleted it, so `-m1` is all you need.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer provides a more precise report, but I accepted the other one because it answers the title question. I upvoted both.

Answer (score 0):

For whoever want it in P4V:

1. go to Depot view
2. click in the top left on the filter icon and choose 'Show Deleted Depot Files'
3. In the Depot tree choose the file you want and look on it's history in the history view